# Mailables in Artisan command are failing

Tags: laravel

In my scheduler I call an artisan command. In that artisan command I send an email like so:

```php
Use App\Mail\Onboarding\OnboardingEmail;
Use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

// And then in the handle() method ($user is defined before this happens):
$message = (new OnboardingEmail($user))->onQueue('email');
Mail::to($user->email)->queue($message);
```

Which produces the following error:

```
Error: The script tried to call a method on an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "App\Mail\
Onboarding" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded
_before_ unserialize() gets called or provide an autoloader to load the class definition in long-path-here/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/SendQueuedMailable.php:65
```

I never encountered this before. Normally I dispatch a Job from the artisan command and the Job then sends the email. But the setup described above is a lot simpler and the email still is processed by the queue, so would like to do it this way.

Is there anything different in dispatching an email in an artisan command vs doing it in a job that causes this error?

Contents of `OnboardingEmail`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mail\Onboarding;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class OnboardingEmail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Onboarding - ' . config('app.name'))
            ->from(config('app.contact_email_from'), config('app.name'))
            ->markdown('emails.onboarding', [
                'user' => $this->user,
            ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your Onboarding class contains a namespace and is this namespace `App\Mail\Onboarding` correct? Maybe you can provide the contents of the `App\Mail\Onboarding` class.

Comment: Yep the namespace is correct. It is actually called `OnboardingEmail`, just updated the question with the contents of the class.